# The functions in the picture are the only ones satisfying these 3 properties?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, analysis, examples-counterexamples

I am looking for an example of a continuous function $f$ such that $0\not\in Dom(f)$ and which behaves like

$$\frac{a|x|-b}{|x|^2}.$$

In particular, it has to be such that:

**1.** it is below $-\frac{1}{|x|}$ when $0<|x|<\varepsilon$ for $\varepsilon$ small;

**2.** there exists at least a point in which it is positive;

**3.** it goes to $0$ as $|x|\to \infty$.

My question is: there are kind of functions than the one exhibited above which comply with assumptions $1.$, $2.$ and $3.$?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Was the link supposed to show a graph?

Comment: I don't know why the graph is blank. Anyway, I meant the function $\frac{a|x|-b}{|x|^2}$ for $a, b>0$.

Comment: @JeanMarie I think that your example does not comply with assumption $1.$

Comment: @C. Bishop You are right.

Comment: $-e^{\frac{1}{|x|}}+1<-\frac{1}{|x|}$. Then for $(2)$ maybe try to connect a function that has a positive value and make a piecewise function

Comment: Your functions work but are obviously not the only possible ones. One can imagine a bunch of other ones. Imo your question is not precise enough.

Comment: Maybe: $-\frac{1}{\left|\left(\frac{x}{\left(n\right)}\right)\right|}$ for $0<n<1$

Comment: On which domain are the functions defined and continuous? (The first property obviously implies that $f$ is not continuous at $x=0$.)